# Breaking equations with breqn

Tags: equations, line-breaking, breqn

I am new to using the `breqn` package. It looks good, but I get an odd behaviour when an equation can almost fit in the page but not quite: the alignment gets completely wrong. Is there a way to fix this?

For the example, I used the minipage environment at various sizes. `\fbox` is only there to show the borders.

Compiling the example below gives good results for small sizes and big sizes, but for `15em`, `16em` and `17em`,the second equation gets out of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newcommand{\myequation}[1]{
  \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{#1}
      Size #1:
      \begin{dgroup*}
        \begin{dmath*}
          (x+\cdots+y+\cdots + z) - (x+\cdots + z) = 0
        \end{dmath*}
        \begin{dmath*}
          A = 0 
        \end{dmath*}
      \end{dgroup*}
      Text
    \end{minipage}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\myequation{5em} \qquad \myequation{6em} \qquad \myequation{9em} \\
\myequation{13em} \qquad \myequation{15em} \\
\myequation{16em} \\
\myequation{17em} \\
\myequation{18em} \\
\myequation{30em}

\end{document}
```

With some versions of breqn and the expl3 bundle, the following code may need to be added to the preamble:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \intexpr_eval:w \int_eval:w
\cs_set_eq:NN \intexpr_eval_end: \int_eval_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting the maintainer of the package? Perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: @Bruno There is a version of `breqn` on CTAN that is newer than this question. Does it fix the problem?

Comment: @Seamus: I just installed TeX Live 2011, and it doesn't seem to be fixed.

Comment: @Seamus: actually, it seems that the version of breqn on CTAN is v0.98a, from 2009. However, the mh bundle (containing breqn) was updated. Maybe you mistook this update for an update of breqn (its modification date is indeed very recent)?

Comment: @Bruno yes looking at this, I think you are right. It seems like the mh bundle being updated gave a newer upload date to the same `breqn` version. Have you tried contacting the author as pmav99 suggested? This could well be a bug...

Comment: It is also possible that Latex simply allows for exiting out of the box too easily. It may be possible to crank up the overfull \hbox error badness.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To understand what is happening here, I cleaned the code a bit and used colored rules than fboxes. I have also used a loop to typeset the various boxes. This way it was easier to modify the widths and see what is happening at the transition points.

Firstly, we view a typeset box that has an adequate width to handle the equations. We see that it correctly typesets these, aligning them at the equal sign and centering them.

[image]

Now what happens when we change the width of the box? TeX starts squeezing the first equation to fit within the width constraints.  For the second equation though, since it fits it will keep the width of the box constant. Oops! the two equations do not align anymore, but have small differences until about 185pt when the first equation is stretched to what TeX thinks is a good equation display.

[image]

Next we view the logical issues in the `breqn` algorithm by forcing a break at a `160pt` width and typesetting the following boxes to have some visual clues:

[image]

It is obvious that the original good position marked to break the equation and at which the second equation is aligned is based on the *unstretched*  first equation. This should have gone through another iteration and be checked against the new position of the equal sign or a trigger should have been switched to let TeX take over and position the second equation at its natural position. A bad combination of `hsize` and the type of equations entered can also create a problem that is intractable and will just produce a badly typeset box Q.E.D?

Here is a new MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{breqn}
\overfullrule1pt
\fboxsep=0.4pt
\def\myequation#1{%
     \hbox to 0pt{\color{orange}\rule{#1}{2pt}}   
       \hsize#1
        Size #1:%
      \begin{dgroup*}[frame={0.4pt},framesep=0pt,compact]
         \begin{dmath*}
          (x+\cdots+y+\cdots + z) - (x+\cdots +2) = 0
        \end{dmath*}
        \begin{dsuspend}
          and
       \end{dsuspend}
        \begin{dmath*}[frame={0pt}]
         a=0
        \end{dmath*}
      \end{dgroup*}
    \hbox to 0pt{\color{orange}\rule{#1}{2pt}} 
}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=160pt,165pt,190pt\do{%
   \hsize\next
    \myequation\next\par
 }
\end{document}
```

To fix it, requires manual intervention (just for the problematic ones), modify as follows:

```
  \begin{dmath*}[frame={0pt}]
    $a=0$
  \end{dmath*}
```

to left align or  `\hbox to 91pt {\hfill $a=0$}` to align, the 91pt was found by trial and error.

[image]

You can use Patrick's `\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}` to see the final boxing:

[image]

Note the box has been drawn with the corrected parameters, as explained above.