# \left and \right in equation across multiple lines

Tags: pdftex, amsmath, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left/Right across multiline equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/left-right-across-multiline-equation)

Could someone explain why I can't get the `left` and `right` commands to work correctly

**code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:foo}
s_{i}^{G}= & \min
\left
(
   \sqrt
   {          \min
      ( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      ) 
      + 
         y
   }
   ,\\
   & 
   \sqrt
   {          \min
      ( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      ) 
      + 
      \min 
      ( 
         (
            y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2
      )
   } 
\right
)
\end{align}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\left`, `\right` constructs can **not** cross alignment boundaries, nor be on different lines.  You need to close it with a `\right.` and begin it again with a `\left.` on the next line, or after the alignment points.  Also, no need to put `align` within `equation`. The `\align` environment is all that is needed.

Comment: @PeterGrill on the wiki page it shows that you can http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A

Comment: You should note that the first `left\{` is closed with a `\right.` on the first line, and the opened with a `\left.` on the second line.

Comment: Oh that's what the `left.` is. Could you, in the form of an answer, explain what the `left. {}` means, then I will accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once we

1. replace the `align` environment to `aligned` (since it is within the `equation` environment and you want a single equation number).
2. add a closing `\right.` before the end of the first line, and
3. add an opening `\left(` on the second line after the alignment point

we get:

[image]

The `\left` and `\right` constructs can **not** cross line, or alignment points. If there is a need to open a `\left` on one line and close it on a subsequent line, then the first line needs to have a `\right.` *before* the end of the line, and the next line needs to have a `\left.` *before* the closing `\right` construct.
 Hence the `\left`, `\right` are balanced on each line. Similar logic applies to each side of an alignment point.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{eq:foo}
s_{i}^{G}= & \min
\left(
   \sqrt
   {          \min
      ( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      ) 
      + 
         y
   }
\right.
   ,\\
   & 
\left.
   \sqrt
   {          \min
      ( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      ) 
      + 
      \min 
      ( 
         (
            y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2
      )
   } 
\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what happened to the `\begin{equation}`?

Comment: You can't use `align` within `equation`. Perhaps you are thinking of `aligned`, which you can use within `equation`.

Comment: ya but this is an equation so I need it numbered

Comment: This method will produce different sized left and right delimiters if one part of the equation is taller than the other.

Comment: @IanThompson: Yep that is correct. This question was more about the use of the `\left`, `\right` construct. The re-size issue is addressed at [Left/Right across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/left-right-across-multiline-equation).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is an example of why the `\left...\right` construct is more problematic than useful in some situations. I propose to use the `\bigX`, `\BigX`, `\biggX`, `\BiggX` family of commands instead; they do not need to be paired and one doesn't have to make manual adjustments when a line change occurs and the lines don't have the same height.

Below, two variations of the expression using this family of commands (the size of the inner parentheses was also corrected); the second one using additionally `\smash`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{eq:foo}
s_{i}^{G}= & \min
\biggl(
   \sqrt
   {
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
         y
   }
   ,\\
   &\quad 
   \sqrt
   {
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
      \min 
      \bigl( 
         (
            y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2
      \bigr)
   } 
\biggr)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{eq:foo}
s_{i}^{G}= & \min
\Bigl(
   \sqrt
   {\smash[b]{
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
         y
   }}
   ,\\
   &\quad 
   \sqrt
   {\smash[b]{
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
      \min 
      \bigl( 
         (
            y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2
      \bigr)
   }}\, 
\Bigr)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Guido** mentions in his comment, a solution for the problem of the displacement of the equation number is to replace the combination of `equation` and `aligned` with `multline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\label{eq:foo}
s_{i}^{G}=  \min
\biggl(
   \sqrt
   {
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
         y
   }
   ,\\
   \sqrt
   {
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
      \min 
      \bigl( 
         (
            y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2
      \bigr)
   } 
\biggr)
\end{multline}

\begin{multline}
s_{i}^{G}= \min
\Bigl(
   \sqrt
   {\smash[b]{
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
         y
   }}
   ,\\
   \sqrt
   {\smash[b]{
      \min
      \bigl( 
         (
            x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x
         )
            ^2  
      \bigr) 
      + 
      \min 
      \bigl( 
         (
            y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2, 
         (
            h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y
         )
            ^2
      \bigr)
   }}\, 
\Bigr)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the problem of the displacement of the equation number a solution in to replace the combination of `equation` and `aligned` with `multline`

Comment: @Guido Thank you. I've incorporated your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, `\left(` and `\right.` are pairs, not `\left(` and `\right)`.
There is a package called [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) that provides the possibility to use `\left` and `\right` across linebreaks:

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
s_{i}^{G}= & \min
\left(\sqrt{\min((x_{i}^{G}-x)^2,(w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x)^2)+y}\right., \notag\\
   & \left.\sqrt{\min((x_{i}^{G}-x)^2,(w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x)^2)+\min((y_{i}^{G}-y)^2, (h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y)^2)}\right)
\end{align}

\begin{dmath}
s_{i}^{G}= \min \left(\sqrt{\min((x_{i}^{G}-x)^2,(w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x)^2)+y},\\
          \mathrel{\phantom{=}} \sqrt{\min((x_{i}^{G}-x)^2,(w_{T} - x_{i}^{G}-x)^2)+\min((y_{i}^{G}-y)^2, (h_{T} - y_{i}^{G}-y)^2)}\right)
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

The macro `\notag` hides the equation tag in the first line since both lines correspond to one and only one equation (or you use the `aligned` environment).

#### Output

[image]

#### Drawbacks

Closing `\left(` with `\right.` works fine as long as both parts of the equation are of equal heights. For an equation like <sub><sup>(this is only a example, neither the equation itself nor the horizontal space in front of the second part should be a point of discussion)</sup></sub>:

```
\begin{align}
    x & = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right. \notag \\
     & \quad  \left. {} + 1\right)
\end{align}
```

The output does not look good:
[image]

Again, you can use `breqn` or, and this needs the author's attention, `\vphantom`:

```
\begin{align}
    x & = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right. \notag \\
      & \quad  \left. {\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}} + 1\right)
\end{align}

\begin{dmath}
    x = \left( \frac{1}{2} \\
        \mathrel{\phantom{=}} {} + 1\right)
\end{dmath}
```

Output:
[image: pic 3]