# A way of handling \left and \right brackets

Tags: math-mode, grouping

I'm looking a way of making something like this:

```
\underbrace{
    \left[\nabla\times
    \left[\nabla\times
    \left[\ldots\nabla\times
}_{
    \infty\text{-times taking curl operator}
}
    \mathbf{V}\right]\right]\ldots\right] = ?
```

Comment: Related: [Left/Right across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612) and [\left and \right in equation across multiple lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73964) (applies to terms in different scopes as well)

Comment: Three `\left`s and four `\right`s by the way … :)

Comment: I don't see a reason for `\left` and `\right` here since they don't contain anything large. Wouldn't simple `\underbrace{[\nabla\times[\nabla\times[\cdots\nabla\times}_{\infty\text{-times taking curl operator}}\mathbf{V}]]\cdots]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to achieve this inserting an appropriate \right and \left null delimiters:

```
\left.
\right.
```

The correspondent code would be:

```
\underbrace{
    \left[\nabla\times
    \left[\nabla\times
    \left[\ldots\nabla\times
    \right.\right.\right.
}_{
    \infty\text{-times taking curl operator}
}
    \mathbf{V}\left.\left.\left.\right]\right]\right]\ldots\right] = ?
```

Comment: Either setting `\nulldelimiterspace=0pt` inside the formula or adding `\kern-3\nulldelimiterspace` (or `\kern-4\nulldelimiterspace`) help to get rid of the additional spacing by `\left.` or `\right.`.

Comment: As far as I see, your solution would not wrong  if there were `\frac{V}{W}` instead of `\mathbf{V}`. I think that `\vphantom` should be used here at the proper places.