# Big Parenthesis in different lines

Tags: equations

I am trying to type two or three lines using big parenthesis inserting some sentences. I am  using this but it does not work for me.

```
\documentclass{12 pt}{article} 

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
& & (product of (A\times_{c} B) by C)\nonumber\\
& &\times_{c}  D) by E.
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

I want to use the parenthesis are big not the small usual one.

Comment: Please see [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln), suggesting to use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment(s) as opposed to `eqnarray`.

Comment: ...then, the following provides a solution: [`\left` and `\right` in equation across multiple lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73964/5764)

Comment: There's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines (though it might be a bit 'dangerous' to recommend `breqn`).

Comment: As Werner says, [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf).

Comment: @ Werner, thank you very much. I tried by using align and \left( \right) and it works for the same line  but if \left( in one line and \right) is in another line then it does not work. Is this mean am I missing somethings?

Comment: use `\bigl(` on one line and `\bigr)` on another (or `\Bigl` or `\biggl` etc.

Comment: The correct is to use `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` with brackets for the option.

Comment: @Rajesh Any feedback concerning David Carlisle's answer? Is it what you want? If not can you explain more precisely what you want as output?

Comment: @ Ludovic C, Thank you. David answer works perfectly. Thank you David.