# Brackets and label in align environment

Tags: brackets

I want to write a little system of two equations with a left bracket over the two lines. Moreover I want to label each of these equations in order to refer to them.

I wrote this :

```
The system of the two equations \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2} :  

\begin{align}  
  \left\{  
  \label{eq1}  
  x+2y=8\\  
  \label{eq2}  
  x-y=3  
  \right.  
\end{align}
```

However the compilation is failing. But this is working if I remove the `\left\{` and `\right.` parts.

Comment: `\left...\right` can not break across lines.  You need to use `\bigl...\bigr` and their cousins.

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases what you're after?

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73974/15925

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `empheq` package; see the minimal example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
    The system of the two equations \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2} :  
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align} 
        x+2y=8 \label{eq1}\\
        x-y=3 \label{eq2}
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```